# Sortable tables in Django

Tags: python, django

I read some of the other posts about this and some recommendations involved javascript and using other libraries.  I did something quick by hand, but I'm new to Django and Python for that matter so I'm curious if this isn't a good way to do it.

HTML

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="?sort=to">To</a></td>
            <td><a href="?sort=date">Date</a></td>
            <td><a href="?sort=type">Type</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% for record in records %}
        <tr><td>{{record.to}}</td><td>{{record.date}}</td><td>{{record.type}}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

View

```
headers = {'to':'asc',
         'date':'asc',
         'type':'asc',}

def table_view(request):
    sort = request.GET.get('sort')
    if sort is not None:
        if headers[sort] == "des":
            records = Record.objects.all().order_by(sort).reverse()
            headers[sort] = "asc"
        else:
            records = Record.objects.all().order_by(sort) 
            headers[sort] = "des"
    else:
        records = Record.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("table.html",{'user':request.user,'profile':request.user.get_profile(),'records':records})
```

Comment: I don't get your code : the headers dict is never sent back to the client, so for me, the inner test will always fall back to the else part and consequently, everything will always be sorted in asc order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me. I'd suggest one minor refactoring in the view code:

```
headers = {'to':'asc',
         'date':'asc',
         'type':'asc',}

def table_view(request):
    sort = request.GET.get('sort')
    records = Record.objects.all()

    if sort is not None:
        records = records.order_by(sort)

        if headers[sort] == "des":
            records = records.reverse()
            headers[sort] = "asc"
        else:
            headers[sort] = "des"

    return render_to_response(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

My first port of call for sortable tables is usually sorttable.js ( http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ )

or sortable-table ( http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/ )

Comment: sorttable.js is the best! works perfectly with Django (script in "static" folder + header configured)

Comment: It's ok provided the table's items are not paged.